# Query calculating average of values including NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a query as follows:

```
UPDATE table SET result = ROUND((col1 + col2)/2, 2);
```

This is fine if there is a value in both col1 and col2 but if one of them is null then it returns null. How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
UPDATE table 
SET result = ROUND(
    (coalesce(col1, 0) + coalesce(col2, 0)
    / nullif( (col1 is not null) + (col2 is not null), 0), 
2);
```

The numerator adds both columns, while turning `null` values to `0`. The denominator counts how many values are not `null`. In other words, if there are two non-`null`  values, you get their average, while if there is just one you get the value itself.

If both values are `null`, the `result` is still `null` (which seems like the relevant thing to do here).

Comment: Thanks - the coalesce(colx, 0) did the trick. Much appreciated.